# How to implement a Welcome screen using Win UI 3

Tags: c#, user-interface, winui-3

I'm developing a Welcome Screen using WinUI 3 like below:

1. Click the back and next button to navigate 3 pages.
2. The page content is displayed in the area above the horizontal line in the mian window.
3. There are three dots to show how many pages and which is current page.

Question:

Here is the example I tried, but it use the whole window to navigate the pages, How to use the part of the main window to display the pages?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages?tabs=wasdk

MainWindow.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="BasicNavigation.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BasicNavigation"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
   
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

// App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    m_window = new MainWindow();

    // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
    Frame rootFrame = new Frame();
    rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;
    // Navigate to the first page, configuring the new page
    // by passing required information as a navigation parameter
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), args.Arguments);

    // Place the frame in the current Window
    m_window.Content = rootFrame;
    // Ensure the MainWindow is active
    m_window.Activate();
}

void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new Exception("Failed to load Page " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
}
```

[image]

Comment: By "screen" you mean a separate window (dialog)? or the MainWindow itself?

Comment: Thanks. a separate window. Do you happen to know if there is a name for that 3 dots control in my attached picture that shows how many pages and the current page number, I also like to know how to implement that using Win UI 3.

Comment: I think you mean the `Carousel` control. As others mentioned, you should consider post another question.

Comment: Thank you, for anyone interested. It is called PipsPager in Win UI 3 Gallery.
https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/tree/main/WinUIGallery/ControlPages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, you first create a RootFrame and load the MainPage inside it.
so in this case You have a Window which host a Frame and this Frame Host MainPage.
if you want to show your Slider in part of your Page, you should add a frame in a place you want!.
so, in your MainPage put another Frame:

```
<MainPage
.........>
<Grid>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Frame x:Name="SliderFrame" Grid.Column="1"/>
<Grid>
your other Elements
</Grid>
</Grid>
```

so you should load your slider page inside SliderFrame

Comment: Thanks, @Katana. Do you happen to know if there is a name for that 3 dots control in my attached picture that shows how many pages and the current page number, I also like to know how to implement that using Win UI 3.

Comment: i think you can use pipspager  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/pipspager